# Synonym für "Zauber"

Tags: synonym

Ich schreibe eine High-Fantasy Geschichte. Lebewesen in dieser Geschichte können Magie anwenden (ein im Körper befindliches System produziert Mana).

Nun ist "Magie" das eigentliche Wort für die Sache. Aber "zaubern" ist das Wort der Tätigkeit. Ich finde, dass "Zauber" sowie "zaubern" immer irgendwie "kindisch" klingt und suche deshalb ein Synonym für eben jene Wörter.

Mir fällt nur "Spruch" ein, der einfach eine Abkürzung für Zauberspruch ist. Ein Wort, welches aber das "magie-ieren" an sich beschreibt fehlt mir aber.

Comment: Hi Raildex! Wir vermeiden hier, die Inhalte von Wörterbüchern zu reproduzieren - wir werden einfach niemals so gut sein, wie ein Wörterbuch. Hast du schon in einem Synonymwörterbuch nachgeschaut? Falls ja, was sind deine Ergebnisse?

Comment: Du nennst bereits "Magie" und "Mana", welche Eigenschaften müsste denn ein Kandidat erfüllen, die diese nicht haben?

Comment: *klingt kindisch* ist eine subjektive Einschätzung, die ich nicht teile. Die Textkorpora von DWDS stützen das meiner Einschätzung nach auch nicht. Wenn die Standard-Alternativen *hexen* und *beschwören* nicht funktionieren, wird man zu Mehrwort-Formulierungen greifen müssen.

Comment: https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/zauber.php

Comment: "Magie wirken" wäre noch eine Möglichkeit.

Comment: Je nach Kontext wäre "hexen" (als Verb) auch möglich, ist aber etwas negativ angehaucht.

Answer (score 4):

Es ist wahrscheinlich, dass eine Gesellschaft, die zu einem wesentlichen Teil auf Magie basiert, auch eine Begrifflichkeit findet, wenn sie darüber sprechen will (von daher kein Wunder, dass **wir** dafür kein Wort haben).

Du bist der Autor, du definierst diese Gesellschaft, also lass' dir was einfallen.

Besondere Handwerke (in so einer Gesellschaft kann Magie wohl durchaus als "Handwerk" durchgehen) haben immer auch besondere Verben für ihre Tätigkeiten gehabt, die in der "normalen" Sprache möglicherweise vorkommen, aber mit anderer Bedeutung, oder auch solche, die speziell für das Handwerk sind. (Siehe z.B. die Verben "strecken" und "strehlen" als Beispiele aus der Metallverarbeitung für beide Kategorien).

Ich denke, du machst es dir als Autor am einfachsten (und, gleichzeitig auch ein bißchen interessanter), wenn du einfach ein Verb erfindest, dass einen "magischen" Anklang hat. Vielleicht kein besonders literarisch wertvolles, aber immerhin ein Beispiel: Die Perry-Rhodan-Romane haben aus ähnlichen Gründen das Verb "espern" (fürs Gedankenlesen) erfunden (oder möglicherweise auch im Grimm gefunden, denn dort kommt es tatsächlich vor) und verwenden das erfolgreich seit Jahrzehnten.

Answer (score 2):

- Warum nicht ein Wort erfinden? Vielleicht in Anlehnung an ein [mittelhochdeutsches Wort](http://www.mhdwb-online.de/wb.php?buchstabe=A&portion=0) aus dem Bedeutungsumfeld von zaubern
- Je nachdem was die Charaktere mit dem Mana so tun, oder welche körperlichen Anzeichen es für das Zaubern gibt, kann man auch eigentlich anders besetzte Wörter benutzen: Er umspann ihn mit Manafäden... Sie warf ihr Mana... Der Spruch lenkte das Mana... Sie spie ihm eine Wolke aus Mana... Er formte das Mana zu einem Hammer und drosch... An feinen Manafäden geführt tapste die Maus wie eine kleine graue Marionette...
- Steh dazu. 'Schwul' wurde von einer tödlichen Beleidung zu einer selbstverständlichen Selbstbeschreibung . Gandalf ist ein Zauberer - mehr street cred kann der Begriff wohl kaum bekommen.

Answer (score 0):

Das Wort Zaubern klingt nicht notwendig kindisch. Wer weiß, dass er ein Phantasybuch kauft, wird so etwas wohl erwarten. Nur an Zauber im eigentlichen Wortsinne zu glauben gilt als kindisch.

Metaphorisch ist der Gebrauch aber gang und gäbe: "Pélé zaubert im gegnerischen Strafraum", "Mit ihren Blicken hat sie ihn verzaubert", "Moderne Technik ist von reiner Zauberei nicht zu unterscheiden."

Alternativen mit Magie:

- Magie bewirken
- Magie betreiben

Je nach konkreter Form der Magie:

- verwandeln
- verhexen
- weghexen
- beamen
- eine Nase ans Knie hexen
- gesundbeten